# Vuejs: shared components used on multiple pages disappeared

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

right now, I'm writing a single-page-application in vue.js using vue-router. Pages like the homepage, sign-in page etc. all share a navigation and footer component. On a few pages however, I need the entire screen so that the navigation and footer shall not be displayed.

Hence, I decided to nest components and include the navigation and footer component when necessary. My problems now is, that the navigation and footer template disappeared on **all** pages.

**Edit**: A more complete demo can be found in [this Github repository](https://github.com/digitalcraftsman/vuejs-stackoverflow-demo).

Here's a simplified version of the files I'm using:

index.html:

```html
<div id="app">
  <router-view></routerview> 
</div>
```

router.js:

```
import Homepage from './homepage.vue';
import SignIn from './signin.vue';

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', component: Homepage},
    {path: '/signin', component: SignIn},
    ]
})
```

homepage.vue and signin.vue components:

```
<template>
  <navigation></navigation>  
    // some page-specific content
  <footer-vue></footer-vue>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from './navigation.vue';
import Footer from './footer.vue';

export default {
  components: {
      'navigation': Navigation,
      'footer-vue': Footer,
  },
}
</script>
```

A component without navigation and footer:

```
<template> 
// some page-specific content
</template>
```

Is it even possible to nest components this way? I hope someone is able to point me into the right direction.

Comment: Any console errors? Looks like you have multiple root nodes in your template, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Neither `npm run build` shows any errors (I'm using the webpack-simple) template nor does the developer console in the browser.

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not you have multiple root nodes in your real templates? Or is that just a mistake in preparing the examples for this question?

Comment: I created a Github repository for a more complete example. Feel free to have a look. You can find the link in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `homepage.vue` and `signin.vue` have invalid templates. e.g.

```html
<template>
    <navigation></navigation>
    <h1>The homepage</h1>
    <footer-vue></footer-vue>
</template>
```

This is not allowed as it has 3 root nodes. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

You need to wrap it to get it to work:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <navigation></navigation>
        <h1>The homepage</h1>
        <footer-vue></footer-vue>
    </div>
</template>
```

Note that this limitation does not apply to functional components and is also expected to be lifted for all components in Vue 3.

Much more worrying is that you're not seeing any errors messages for this. You really need to look into that as it suggests there's something very much amiss with your development setup.

An example of the error message you should be seeing:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<div></div><div></div>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Wrapping the templates for the homepage and sign-in page in a div solved the problem. I just started a few hours ago learning Vue.js. I didn't expect to get stuck by such a little detail. Anyways, thank you again @skirtle! Regarding the error messages: I'll have a look at that.